# What plane is this, looks a lot like a BAe-146-100 or an Avro 146-RJ100, however with only 2 engines?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I saw it and took a picture. It is flying out of Phoenix Sky Harbor International Airport. It landed at about 5:27 if that matters. It is a green tail livery that extends downward. The wings are above it like on a C172 however the engines are straight under the wings. The engines are fan engines, not props. It looks like the 146-RJ100 with only 2 engines total though.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please add the photos here, do not link a shared drive where they can be removed any time making this question incomplete.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [Fairchild Dornier 328JET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_Dornier_328JET)

Comment: It was a bit of a flop insofar as they stuck turbofans on a straight wing turboprop and ended up with a jet that was too slow to mix with the heavies and regionals flying around at 0.75 or 0.8 Mach, so on busy routes they typically were assigned altitudes under 30000 ft to keep them out of the way of the faster traffic, negating some or most of the benefit of the fan.

Comment: I had to look up it’s Mach performance. Yes, M0.63 is pretty slow for a jet.

Comment: I learned this when I was at a conference once with regional operators and one of them, that operated 328Js along with other types, told me how frustrated they were that ATC was always forcing their planes down to FL260 or 280 because of the overtaking problem, which did a bit of damage to the airplane's business case.  Why even bother with RVSM cert?

Comment: The 328 was developed as a turboprop and marketed to do 345 kts when engineering said it will do 330 tops. So they had to increase installed power and it hit the market when fuel prices were dropping. Management felt it would be a good idea to switch to jets. As a turboprop it was excellent …